# how can I edit the output of csvstat to... csv

Tags: csvkit

How can I edit the output of csvkit's csvstat tool so it is formatted as... CSV?

More specifically, csvstat can output counts & tabulations from the contents of CSV files. For example, the following command will read a file named data.csv and then count & tabulate the values in the column named "pos":

```
csvstat -c pos data.csv --freq
```

The result is a string looking like a Python dictionary:

```
{ "NNP": 2204, "NN": 2035, "IN": 1512, ",": 1039, "NNS": 1006 }
```

Do you know of a quick & easy way to transform this string into CSV? A one-liner? Maybe through the use of another csvkit tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csvkit and jq, you can run

```
csvstat -c pos data.csv --freq | jq -s . | in2csv -I -f json
```

Comment: Perfect. Absolutely perfect. It can not get much simpler. Thank you. aborruso++

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--csv` as another argument as suggested by documentation here: https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/csvstat.html

Comment: Alas, while that is a good guess, and I should have RTFM, the use of --csv does not work. When I issue this:

  csvstat  -c pos data.csv --freq --csv

I get the following error:

   You may not specify --csv and an operation
   (--mean, --median, etc) at the same time.

Bummer.

Comment: I would suggest scripting for this. Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-save-a-Python-Dictionary-to-CSV-file which you can convert a actual dict object in python into a csv.